# Getting the path of an uploaded media file that uses "upload_to" in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to replace the images that will be uploaded for a certain ImageField in my models. Now My models are like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # some resizing here which works fine
```

As you can see, my model saves the file to the `'images/'` directory (because i have different image types that need to go in different sub-directories of `/media`) which will eventually become `'/media/images/'` due to this setting in my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Now the problem is where I'm using the receiver method to delete the previously uploaded image.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Image)
def file_update(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    print(instance.image.path) ### HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    if instance.image:
        path = instance.image.path ### HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        os.remove(path)
```

It's supposed to return this:

```
/home/.../media/images/file.jpg
```

But it returns this:

```
/home/.../media/file.jpg
```

Which obviously results in a `No such file or directory` error. What am I missing?

A simple hack would be to do something like this:

```
path = instance.image.path
name = instance.image.name
correct_path = path.replace(name, 'images/' + name)
```

But that doesn't answer the question of why it happened or what's the correct way of doing it.

---

**UPDATE**:
In case someone is having the same problem, I tried another approach. First, I fetch the object with it's id and then get that path:

```
instance = kwargs['instance']
if instance.id is not None:
    current_image = Image.objects.filter(id=instance.id)[0]
    print(current_image.image.path) ### WORKS FINE
    os.remove(current_image.image.path) ### WORKS FINE
```

This approach has two benefits:

1. The path will be correct.
2. Replacing the image is guaranteed to work because we are getting the path of previously saved object not calculating based on the newly submitted object (which if not existing, can lead to problems of not having an ID yet).

The only downside is an extra database query.

Comment: you may need to overide the `save` method inside `models`, get image path using `self.image.path`

Comment: Just to confirm; the image is correctly saved to the `/media/images/` directory but you are getting an incorrect path when trying to locate the file to delete? What do you get if you print the url `instance.image.url` as mentioned here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage ?

Comment: @chrisbyte Exactly. When I try to get the url it gives just `/media/ImageName.jpg`.

Comment: @Abhyudai I did override that for resizing my images, but isn't that the same thing? I am getting the image object using the `instance`.

Comment: you are using a `pre_save` signal. i guess that might cause this error. just see if it works under a `post_save` signal

Comment: @Abhyudai That is correct. The problem with `post_save` is that django automatically appends some random string to the file name (since it prevents overwrite).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Abhyudai indicated: Your 'problem' only occurs in the `pre_save`. In the `post_save` you are getting the correct path. I suspect that the correct 'path' is only generated when the file is actually saved (before saving the model it has not been written to the final destination.

However, you can still access the required data in your pre_save:

Absolute path of your media dir:

```
instance.image.storage.base_location # /home/.../media
```

The relative path of your upload_to:

```
instance.image.field.upload_to # images/
```

Note the `.field` as we want the field and not the `FieldFile` normally returned

And of course the name of your file

```
instance.image.name
```

Joining all these will give you the path you need to check and delete the existing file, if required

Answer (score 0):

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Image)
def attachment_image_update(sender, **kwargs):
    attachment = kwargs['instance']
    if attachment.id:
        attachment = Image.objects.get(pk=attachment.id)
    try:
        storage, path = attachment.image.storage, attachment.image.path
        storage.delete(path)
    except ValueError:
        print('Error! The image does not exist')
```

or

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Image)
def attachment_image_update(sender, **kwargs):
    attachment = kwargs['instance']

    if attachment.id:
        attachment = Image.objects.get(pk=attachment.id)

    if attachment.image:
        storage, path = attachment.image.storage, attachment.image.path
        storage.delete(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be directly applicable for the OP's case, but, in general:

As explained in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) `upload_to` can be either a string (possibly with datetime formatting), or a callable.

Django uses [`FileField.generate_filename()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4879907223d70ee1a82474d9286ccfa5dae96971/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L324) to combine the `upload_to` value with the actual filename. Note that `ImageField` is a `FileField` subclass.

So, to get a path *relative to the storage root*, you could do something like this:

```py
relative_path = instance.image.field.generate_filename(
    instance=instance, filename='image.jpg'
)
```

For example, if `upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/'`, the above would yield `uploads/2024/01/image.jpg`

Note the `instance` attribute is only actually used if `upload_to` is a callable.

Depending on the [storage class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4879907223d70ee1a82474d9286ccfa5dae96971/django/core/files/storage/base.py#L101), the result may be modified further.