# Access "upload_to" of a Model's FileFIeld in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Model with a FileField like that:

```
class Video(MediaFile):
    """ Model to store Videos """
    file = FileField(upload_to="videos/")
    [...]
```

I'm populating the DB using a cron script.

Is it possible to somehow access the "upload_to" value of the model?
I could use a constant, but that seems messy. Is there any way to access it directly?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59521479

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access this with:

```
Video.file.field.upload_to  # 'videos/'
```

or through the `_meta` object:

```
Video._meta.get_field('file').upload_to  # 'videos/'
```

The [**`upload_to=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) can however also be given a function that takes two parameters, and thus in that case it will not return a string, but a reference to that function.